# Set a Referer header in Mojo::UserAgent

Tags: perl, referer

I am writing a program to access the web using
[`Mojo::UserAgent`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent)

I want to set the `Referer` header value but I do not know how.

#### Perl code

```
my $ua   = Mojo::UserAgent->new();
my $data = $ua->get('https://test.com')->res->body;

print $data,"\n";
```

Answer (score 7):

You would set the `Referer` header the same way you'd set any other request header with [Mojo::UserAgent](https://metacpan.org/pod/Mojo::UserAgent):

```
my $data = $ua->get('https://test.com' => {Referer => 'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50956597'})->res->body;
```

Comment: @KiHunNam [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)